# Construct pattern that match if there is no punctuation between two characters in R stringr

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a text with several people and their speeches. I need to extract people's names with their party membership. The problem that there are people who are not party members and I want them to be excluded.

The text I am working with is constructed in the following way:

```
string = 'Author A. B., party member X. Some text. Author G. H., party Y. Some text. Author K. L., somebody. Text that mentions party. Author R. H., party X. Some text.'
```

My desirable outcome is:

```
'Author A. B., party member X.' 
'Author G. H., party Y.'
'Author R. H., party X.'
```

I used

`str_extract_all(string, '[A-Z]\\w{1,50}\\s[A-Z]\\.\\s[A-Z]\\.,\\s(.*?)party(.*?)\\.')`

as a pattern request, it works well with the exception that it also matches `Author K. L., somebody. Text that mentions party.` and it should be excluded. I tried to implement exception marks `[^\\.]`  and match for `[A-Z]\\w{1,50}\\s[A-Z]\\.\\s[A-Z]\\.,\\s(.*?)[^\\.](.*?)party(.*?)\\.` but is gives wring result.

I need to find a match if there is no dot between the name of the author and the word `party`. If there is a dot between - there should be no match. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Like in here, https://regex101.com/r/1nZ3H3/1? I think that you may even replace `.*?` in `(.*?)party` with `[\w\s]*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
\b[A-Z]\w{1,50}\s[A-Z]\.\s*[A-Z]\.,[^.]*party[^.]*\.
\b[A-Z]\w{1,50}\s[A-Z]\.\s*[A-Z]\.,[\w\s]*party[^.]*\.
```

In code:

```
str_extract_all(string, '\\b[A-Z]\\w{1,50}\\s[A-Z]\\.\\s*[A-Z]\\.,[^.]*party[^.]*\\.')
str_extract_all(string, '\\b[A-Z]\\w{1,50}\\s[A-Z]\\.\\s*[A-Z]\\.,[\\w\\s]*party[^.]*\\.')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hiQssH/1).

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `[A-Z]` - an uppercase ASCII letter (use `\p{Lu}` to match any Unicode uppercase letter)
- `\w{1,50}` - 1 to 50 letters, digits or `_`
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `[A-Z]` - an uppercase ASCII letter
- `\.` - a dot
- `\s*[A-Z]\.` - a whitespace, an uppercase ASCII letter, a dot
- `,` - a comma
- `[^.]*` - 0 or more chars other than `.`
- `[\w\s]*` - 0 or more letters, digits, underscores or whitespaces (no punctuation other than `_`)
- `party` - a word
- `[^.]*\.` - 0 or more chars other than a dot and then a dot.

Comment: Oh, thank you! It workes perfectly well. I messed up with dot notation within `[] `